# Access violation when assigning a changed bitmap to a VCL style

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Delphi XE7 Bitmap Style Designer: When I change an exported bitmap of a Delphi Visual Style (e.g. 'Auric') I get an access violation after importing the png back and try to assign colors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably importing image in following way:

```
Images -> style.png -> Delete -> Add -> Style Assign Colors -> AV
```

Instead do:

```
Images -> style.png -> Update -> Style Assign Colors
```

Comment: @Nobby Then you should describe in your question the exact steps you take, each button click you did, as well as what software you used to modify this png file.

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce the error with second approach. You will have to add more information about what exactly are you doing.

Comment: Delphi XE7 / Tools / Bitmap Style Designer
File / Open / select file 'Carbon.vsf'
Select Images / style.png / Export to desktop
Open 'style.png' with a bitmap editor
Change some colors and save file 'style.png'
In Bitmap Style Designer select Images / style.png / Update / select modified 'style.png' from desktop
In the Open Image dialog select the mask color and press [OK]
[Save]
Style / Assign colors / [Yes] -> sometimes here an access violation appears
[Save]
Style / Test [F9] -> nothing happens or just a small black outline is visible

Comment: Delphi XE7 / Project / Options... / Appearance / select 'Carbon' [OK]
Run the application (32-Bit Debug mode) -> window doesn't open -> sometimes just a small black outline is visible

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one have to edit the png image with Photoshop or Gimp which supports transparency. If I changed the colors in a simple bitmap editor like Paint, the above problems appears.